# Update MySQL using PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a PHP form (update-complaint.php) which has 20 fields (Q1, Q2 - Q20) and shows the data for that current record - all works well from here.  On submit it goes to "updated-complaint.php" and the fields should update in the DB.  If successful it will say so or ERROR.

I have tested it by amending data, submitting it says successful but the database remains the same.  Below is updated-complaint.php.  Can anyone help ?

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="complaints"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET q1='$q1', q2='$q2', q3='$q3' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

The post form is

```
        <?php
            $host="localhost"; // Host name 
            $username="user"; // Mysql username 
            $password="password"; // Mysql password 
            $db_name="db"; // Database name 
            $tbl_name="complaints"; // Table name

            mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

            $id=$_GET['id'];

            // Retrieve data from database 
            $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

            ?>

        <table width="100%" border="0" class="add-record" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
        <td><form name="form1" method="post" action="updated-complaint.php">
```

Comment: $sql="UPDATE '$tbl_name' SET q1='$q1', q2='$q2', q3='$q3' WHERE id='$id'";

Comment: Does your table `id` is numeric or character `id='$id'`?

Comment: @Ranjith you mean `mysqli_*`?

Comment: @Grant you should check the number of records updated. Its possible the query is syntax wise OK, but it updates 0 rows.

Comment: **[mysql_* is deprecated from php 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)** Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*`

Comment: How are you getting $q1 from $_GET['q1'] or $_POST['q1'] or $_REQUEST['q1']? Same for $id...

Comment: `PHP` is removing `mysql` at the end of the year, start learning `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: Yes the DB has "id" and the method is post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET q1='$_REQUEST[q1]', q2='$_REQUEST[q2]', q3='$_REQUEST[q3]' WHERE id='$_REQUEST[id]'";
```

DO NOTE THE COMMENT BY @Ranjith THAT MYSQL_* IS DEPRECATED - use mysqli instead.

Since I didn't know if you were using GET or POST I have just used $_REQUEST, but if you are concerned about security then using POST and $_POST would be better.

Also do note that you should be concerned about security, either escaping the data (mysqli_real_escape) or else preparing the statement before doing the query.  These are important issues, but not the center of the question - therefore the answer at the top of this post stands.

I'm assuming that you have a

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= PRINT THE ID ?>" />
```

or the like in your form so that the $_REQUEST['id'] is being provided to update-complaint.php.

Comment: If the above doesn't work, try putting echo statements in update-complaint.php which display the value of $_REQUEST['id'] and $_REQUEST['q1'] and etc. Do note that the variables are case-sensitive, so $_REQUEST['q1'] is different from $_REQUEST['Q1'].

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO! :)

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$user="user"; // Mysql username 
$pass="password"; // Mysql password 
$dbname="db"; // Database name 
$tableName="complaints"; // Table name 

if ($_POST){
    //for mysql:    
    try {
        //connection: 
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

       //prepare inserting
       $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE  $tableName (name, address, phone) VALUES (:name,:address,:phone) WHERE id = :id");

       //our placeholders, it's magic)) 
       $data = array(
           'id' => $_POST['id'],
           'name' => $_POST['name'],
           'address' => $_POST['address'],
           'city' => $_POST['city'],
       );

       //and now execute our query and substitute data
       //if execute is successful $result will true else false
       $result = $STH->execute($data);

       if ($result){
           echo "UPDATED!";
       }else{
           echo "Error!";
       }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {  
        echo "cannot connect to database";
        echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
}
```

p.s it's simple. i don't check this code, but it must work) 
Thanks for listening)

Answer (score -1):

```
Database Table Description
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_test` (
    `f1` int(3) NOT NULL,
    `f2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `f3` varchar(50) NOT NULL
    );
    --
    -- Dumping data for table `tbl_test`
    --
    INSERT INTO `tbl_test` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`) VALUES
    (1, 'Kathmandu', 'Nepal'),
    (2, 'Bhaktapur', 'Nepal');
```

```
List all records


    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $username="root"; // Mysql username 
        $password=""; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="test"; // Database name 
        $tbl_name="tbl_test"; // Table name 

        // Connect to server and select database.
        mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)
        or die("Error: to connect database server"); 

        mysql_select_db($db_name)
        or die("Error: to select database");

        $sql="Select * from ".$tbl_name;
        $result=mysql_query($sql);      
        echo("");
        echo("SNDistrictCountry");
        if($result){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo("".$row["f1"]. "" . $row["f2"]. "" . $row["f3"]. "");
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "ERROR: to display record(s)";
        }
```

```
Update record

    // Connect to server and select database.
        mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)
        or die("Error: to connect database server"); 

        mysql_select_db($db_name)
        or die("Error: to select database");

        // update data in mysql database 
        $v1=1;
        $v2='Banepa';

        $sql="UPDATE ".$tbl_name." SET f2='".$v2."' WHERE f1=".$v1;
        echo ($sql);
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        if($result){
            echo "Successful";
            echo "
";
            echo "View result";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "ERROR: to update record";
        }
```

Comment: How is this answer related to the question?